# Execute Stored Procedure containing dynamic SQL Sybase

Tags: sql, permissions, execute, dynamic-sql, sap-ase

Why can't i execute a stored procedure which contains Dynamic SQL with non SP owner user?

I can execute it succesfully with the SP owner user, but other users can't.

Nevertheless, i have granted permissions on that SP.

Everything works right while that SP has no Dynamic SQL.

I am using Sybase ASE 15.0.3

Comment: If the user doesn't have access to the base tables, we can't fix that only your dba can fix that.

Comment: I don't want the user that executes the SP has access to any tables.

Comment: They you cannot use dynamic sql. It requires access at teh table level.

Comment: Please improve your 'question' as there is currently no question! Questions end with '?' and without a clear question, there can be no clear answer. :)

Comment: I hope it's already clear, if not, please tell me ;)

Answer (score 2):

I've got it!

When there is Dynamic SQL in the SP, **also** is required to change the execution mode to "dynamic"

```
sp_procxmode sp_name, "dynamic"
```

in order to allow non SP owner users to execute successfully that SP.

Answer (score 0):

To execute a stored procedure the user needs to have access to all tables, views, etc. that might be on it, whether in the *normal* code or in the *dynamic* code!

Comment: At least in Sybase, if a user is granted to exec any SP, there aren't needed extra permissions for a successfull usage. The matter comes when i add dynamic sql within the SP

Comment: I don't agree, the user also needs permission to read (select) the tables. I had that problem last week!

Comment: I found this: _since a user can be granted permission to execute a stored procedure, even if she or he does not have permissions on the tables or views referenced in it_ from [Sybase](http://manuals.sybase.com/onlinebooks/group-as/asg1250e/sqlug/@Generic__BookTextView/42726;pt=42621)

Comment: That doesn't say that it'll work after :) after if she or he try to execute the SP it'll give permission errors on the tables (one at a time).

Comment: That sounds interesting, actually i can use a SP to read a table which i can't with a select statement. I'm using iSQL 11

Comment: In Sybase ASE I had that problem last week, or at least seemed to be that problem :P